# Internet Explorer 8 won't modify HTML5 tags in print stylesheet

Tags: html, printing, header, footer, nav

I was working on a print stylesheet earlier and came across a problem with IE8. I am using HTML5 and several layout tags including header, nav and footer.

For some reason in my print stylesheet the display:none; declaration on these tags is being ignored in IE8 (and I can only assume subsequent lower versions). I first thought that Developer Tools in IE9 could be causing a false representation, however I have a Windows XP installation in VirtualBox which shows the problem also.

My guess its because HTML5 tags aren't seen properly by anything below IE9. The print stylesheet hides the layout tags in Firefox and Chrome.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Edit:

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Ignore the PHP Statements, they are specific to my CMS which is WordPress.

Then I simply hide the layout tags in the print.css:

```
nav,footer { 
display:none;
}
```

This works for IE9, Firefox, Chrome but not in anything lower than IE9. It seems to ignore HTML5 tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you try [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). The main shiv does `document.createElement()` as you have but it's been optimized / minified like crazy. More importantly, it includes [printshiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv-printshiv.js) (IE Print Protector) which will let you style HTML5 elements for print.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about html5shiv but did not know about printshiv. I will certainly be using it for HTML5 projects in the future

Comment: @James, you realize this is what I told you a week ago right?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/). In the Extra, make sure html5shiv /w printshiv is selected. Include this javascript library on your site and it should work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to use html5shiv, as it includes printshiv already. But, your solution is also viable so thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Since all i can do is guess without actually seeing the code, my first guess would be that the html5 shiv that is being used after the css declarations, and the css simply skips the html 5 tags, without applying the css styles to them. Try setting the script at the very top, before any css link tags in the head.

Comment: I don't use html5 shiv. All I've done is write a couple of document.CreateElement Statements for the layout tags

Comment: Can you try moving those up before the print css declaration?
html5 shiv uses basically the same thing.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a workaraound using Javascript by including a pair of functions `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` in which you hide/show the content that should be `display:none`.

Comment: I was thinking I could be even more basic and just add a class onto the layout tag such as nav_noprint and footer_noprint

Comment: If you have an element already in place that you can do that, I'd give it a shot. Otherwise, it's a question of whether you want to add additional elements into the page.

Comment: I might have to as it seems anything lower than IE9 can't select HTML5 tags reliably

Comment: [IE Protector](http://code.google.com/p/ie-print-protector/) takes the approach of using onbeforeprint to swap in < IE9 friendly elements for printing and then reverts in onafterprint. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) also bundles IE Protector, so I think it probably is as good approach as any.

Comment: ^ with this guy. I can affirm for you that trying to style these unsupported HTML5 tags will **not** work. You'd either have to switch the `<nav>` and `<footer>` tags to `<div>`s or use one of these shims.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recomend for the use of [boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for your trouble. Is a nice compilation for web standarts and some know and common issues in almost every browser. It use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and have an awesome stylesheet that have a @media print that you can use for all your printing troubles in all browsers.