# IE 8 ignores media query but max-width media query works

Tags: internet-explorer, css, media-queries

I'm using respond.js on a project and using two media queries with mixed success.

This one: @media only screen and (max-width: 399px) { rules... } - works perfectly well.

This one: @media print { rules... } - does not work at all.

Both media queries are in the same overall style sheet (using boilerplate). I can't understand why IE would ignore one but not the other.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Other browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) work without any problems.

Comment: How strange. IE8 doesn't support CSS3 media queries at all so only `@media print`, which does not use the new syntax, should work and not the first one.

Comment: Thank for the comment - it looks as though most of the obviously visible changes we made in the print stylesheet were attached to html5 elements and that's why we were having the issues. Frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post this morning - not sure how I missed it when I was searching previously:

[Internet Explorer 8 won't modify HTML5 tags in print stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227518/internet-explorer-8-wont-modify-html5-tags-in-print-stylesheet)

The problem I was having was related to using html5 tags since those were the elements I was trying to modify. I was using Modernizr on the page, but the version we were using didn't include html5shiv/printshiv I guess so when we were trying to print the browser was just ignoring the  and other html5 tags referenced in the print stylesheet.

Adding the html5shiv/printshiv libraries for IE solved my issue.